# How can I call any external API (Authentication) in Gulp Project?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Recently I got a project on **gulp**. After much research I got to know about gulp that it's a **task runner** and **automation tool**. However, I couldn't figure it out how to call external API in gulp.

I refer their documentation but got no clear. I don't know whether we can integrate *API* in gulp or not. If not, why this **JS** package. After all, **Frontend** can't be defined without **API** integration.

Can anyone help me out.
Thank You

Comment: What exactly do you need to do in Gulp for this project to work?

Comment: Actually, I bought a mat-theme which is in gulp. There I get all the frontend code in .html and for CSS/JS all are CDN links and that's fine no issue. For external API call we can simply use traditional JS method, but my concern is there any way in gulp so that this API call and data handling becomes easier like other libraries ex. Angular and react.

Comment: Gulp is nothing like Angular or React. It's only a tool to build your project. Once the project is built, the job of Gulp is done. Thus, once the built project is *running* it's not at all associated with Gulp any more. Gulp is an alternative to Webpack, not a frontend library/framework.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.